# how to convert the content in to HTML Format Postmark

Tags: html, node.js, email-templates, postmark

i tried like Below to send content to Postmark email template

```
var username  = "Dear user,<br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Thank you for using our product.&nbsp; &nbsp;<br><b>Note :newly Features introduced </b><br>1.A <br>2.B.<br>3.<br><br>";
  client.sendEmailWithTemplate({
    "From": "abc@gmail.com", 
    "To": "xyz@gmail.com",
    "InlineCss": true,
    "TemplateId":123456,
    "TemplateModel" : {
        "content" : username
    }
    }, function(error, success) {
    if(error) {
        console.error("Unable to send via postmark: " + error.message);
        return;
    }
    console.info("Sent to postmark for delivery")
});
```

when i receive email with template HTML tags are coming as it is. How can i convert them in to HTML Format so that it comes in correct format. Any Suggestions... Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is `client`? Maybe try `TemplateModel: {HtmlBody: username}`?

Comment: Hi @ExplosionPills client is constructor of postmark. var client = new postmark.Client("serverkey");
 i'm using postmark npm module.  "TemplateModel" : { "HtmlBody":username}. no result. nothing is coming even content with tags..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. Generally we use `{{username}}` (in my case var name is username) to show in template. we need to use like this --> `{{{username}}}` .surrounding with extra curly braces to convert the content in HTML format.For reference look here --> [documentation here](https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html) . Thanks.